# Invalid parameter binding Parameter name: file

Tags: c#, oracle, insert

I am writing a method to insert data into oracle in C#. While executing this I am getting 
error `Invalid parameter binding Parameter name: file`
My code is:

```
public static void DatabaseFilePut(MemoryStream fileToPut, OracleConnection con)
    {
        try
        {
           const string preparedCommand =
                @"INSERT INTO user_account_statement (statement_id,session_key,
                  login_id,user_id,account_number,from_date,todate,ipaddress,
                  create_date_time,STATEMENT_FILE)VALUES(1073,
                 'fe79e0345986b5a439c26f731234868b53f877366f529',
                  2335,'204254','108142',to_date('2014-08-23 16:45:06','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
                  to_date('2014-08-23 16:45:06','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'106.79.126.249',
                  to_date('2014-08-23 16:45:06','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), :file)";

            using (var sqlWrite = new OracleCommand(preparedCommand, con))
            {
                sqlWrite.BindByName = true;
                var blobparameter=new OracleParameter
                {
                    OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Blob,
                    ParameterName = "file",
                    Value = fileToPut
                };
                sqlWrite.Parameters.Add(blobparameter);
                sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I have checked the parameter part but not getting exactly what's wrong in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter expects a byte array. I'm not aware that it accepts a memory stream as well. So

```
Value = fileToPut
```

should be

```
Value = fileToPut.ToArray()
```

Comment: now I got error 'ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name'

Comment: You should probably add the hint from the other answer and use an @ symbol for parameters. You are using `ODP.NET`, aren't you?

Comment: @Ashok_Karale: "file" is probably a reserved word. Try changing the parameter name. Via http://ora-01745.ora-code.com/

Comment: @Cory you are awesome. I changed the parameter name and Problem solved.